# Null Pointer Exception at Graphics.drawImage()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-3d

This is the code I am using to draw an image on a J3D Canvas3D:

```
    Graphics g = Canvas.getGraphics(); //Canvas is the Canvas3D
    g.drawImage(new ImageIcon("back/loadingscreen.png").getImage(),
            0, 0, Canvas);
```

however whenever I run the code I get a NullPointerException at the line of g.drawImage(). I have no idea what is causing the exception, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `getGraphics` method is returning `null`. Print the value of `g` in between those two lines to see what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImageIcon is null 
please use this to load your ImageIcon properly

```
 InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("back/loadingscreen.png");
     BufferedImage bufferedImage=ImageIO.read(stream);
     ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);

     Graphics g = Canvas.getGraphics(); 
        g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, Canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Graphics g = Canvas.getGraphics();

if(g==null){

System.out.println("Did not receive any Graphics object from the getGraphics method.");

}

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("back/loadingscreen.png");

if(icon==null){

```
System.out.println("The icon is not received meaning the URL path (back/laodingscreen.png) is probably wrong.");
```

}